# Calculate the volume of a torus

Tags: multiple-integral, solid-of-revolution

I want calculate the volume of the solid obtained by rotating around the $z$-axis $$C=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\;:\; (x-R)^2+z^2\le r^2,y=0\}$$ with $0<r<R$.
Can I use polar coordinates?

Comment: Polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$? What does that mean?

Comment: Polar coordinates in xz plane

Answer (score 6):

By [Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem#The_second_theorem), the volume of the [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) is given by
$2\pi R\cdot \pi r^2$.

The same result can be obtained by using integration and [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system): the torus is generated by the disc $C$ is
$$T=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\;:\; \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R\right)^2+z^2\le r^2\right\}$$
and therefore
$$\begin{align}\text{Vol}(T)&=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\rho=R-r}^{R+r}\int_{z=-\sqrt{r^2-(\rho-R)^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-(\rho-R)^2}} dz \rho d\rho  d \theta\\
&=4\pi\int_{\rho=R-r}^{R+r}\sqrt{r^2-(\rho-R)^2}\, \rho d\rho\\
&=4\pi r^2\int_{s=-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-s^2}\, (rs+R) ds\\
&=4\pi r^2R\int_{s=-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-s^2}\,ds=2\pi R \cdot \pi r^2
\end{align}$$
where $s=(\rho-R)/r$ (the integral of $rs$ is zero by symmetry).

Comment: I want solve with integration

Comment: Sure. $$V = \int_0^{2\pi R} \pi r^2\,\mathrm{d}s = 2\pi^2 r^2R$$ This uses a volume element $\pi r^2\,\mathrm{d}s$, which is a thin cylindrical element of radius $r$, and we integrate it around the circle of radius $R$.

Comment: The professor want use only chance of coordinates,polar,spherical

Comment: @GiuliaB. See my edited answer.

Comment: But I have C and not  T in the text

Comment: $C$ is the disc that, by rotating around the $z$-axis, generates the torus $T$

Answer (score 3):

Using cylindrical coordinates (As $r$ is usually used in this coordinates I will use $S$ instead): by symmetry, $(x-R)^2 + z^2 = S^2$ gives

$$
(r-R)^2 + z^2 = S^2 \implies r = R\pm\sqrt{S^2-z^2},\quad z = \sqrt{S^2-(r-R)^2}.$$
$$
V = \int_0^ {2\pi}\int_{-S}^S\int_{R-\sqrt{S^2-z^2}}^{R+\sqrt{S^2-z^2}}r\,drdzd\theta = \cdots
$$
$$V = \int_0^ {2\pi}\int_{R-S}^{R+S}\int_{-\sqrt{S^2-(r-R)^2}}^{\sqrt{S^2-(r-R)^2}}r\,dzdrd\theta = \cdots
$$
(What is better?)

Alternatively, you can do a cov adapted to the problem:
$$
\eqalign{
r &= R + s\cos\psi\cr
x &= (R + s\cos\psi)\cos\theta\cr
y &= (R + s\cos\psi)\sin\theta\cr
z &= s\sin\psi
}
$$
$$(s,\theta,\psi)\in[0,S]\times[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$$

$$
\eqalign{J
&=
\left|\matrix{
\cos\psi\cos\theta &     -(R+s\cos\psi)\sin\theta & -s\sin\psi\cos\theta\cr
\cos\psi\sin\theta &\hfill(R+s\cos\psi)\cos\theta & -s\sin\psi\sin\theta\cr
\sin\psi           &           0              &  s\cos\psi
}\right|\cr
&= 
(R+s\cos\psi)s\left|\matrix{
\cos\psi\cos\theta &     -\sin\theta & -\sin\psi\cos\theta\cr
\cos\psi\sin\theta &\hfill\cos\theta & -\sin\psi\sin\theta\cr
\sin\psi           &      0      &  \cos\psi
}\right| = (R+s\cos\psi)s.
}
$$

$$
V =
\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\int_0^S\!\int_0^{2\pi}(R+s\cos\psi)s\,d\psi ds d\theta =
\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\!\int_0^S 2\pi Rs\,ds d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\pi RS^2\,d\theta = 2\pi^2 R S^2.
$$